# REST naming conventions when used with Spring MVC

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc

i'm developing a SpringMVC app with JPA with basic objects.

Using this basic REST convention: https://restfulapi.net/resource-naming/ for a entity named **customer**, I have:

```
HTTP GET http://xxxx/customers  //Get all customers
HTTP POST http://xxxx/customers  //Create new customers
HTTP GET http://xxxx/customers/{id}  //Get customer for given Id
HTTP PUT http://xxxx/customers/{id}  //Update customer  for given Id
HTTP DELETE http://xxxx/customers/{id}  //Delete customer  for given Id
```

This is pretty straightforward. Now, how should be name the url from the pages that calls those methods?

For example, first I want to show all values using datatables.

Should I use the same URL GET http://xxxx/customers  but somehow asking for the HTML view, not the data? example using a parameter: http://xxxx/customers?view or something like that. O Should I use a complete new set or URL?

The same, what should be the URL for the page that show only one record(example, I clicked the **customer YYY** in the previous datatable). Should be GET:http://xxxx/customers/yyy?view or something completly new?

In this case with Spring If I detect the parameter **view** I respond with a modelAndView result, and if not just with a **json** including the data.

Comment: your question is pretty unclear to me

Comment: In one side, I have the rest methods. In the other, the web that use those methods. Should the URLs for those calls be the same?

Comment: I don't know about the convention but for me it should me same so that will be figure out easily by others

Comment: The spelling in the URI is not of relevance in a REST environment as the URI isn't parsed or analyzed by clients anyway, it is just invoked based on other decision factors such as link-relation names and accompanying identifying data such as a summary of the content. In regards to selecting which representation format to receive, HTTP here uses [content-type negotiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_negotiation)

Comment: What are you saying is unclear. I am assuming you have Spring MVC with jQuery in the UI and have Ajax requests to get the data from the server. If so then the view path and the rest api path should be isolated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This is pretty straightforward. Now, how should be name the url from the pages that calls those methods?

The real answer, as noted by Roman Vottner, is "anything you want".

One thing that I think will help right away -- stop thinking about "methods", and think about documents.

> HTTP is an application protocol whose *application domain* is the transfer of documents over a network -- [Jim Webber](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc)

The target-uri for the documents are just that: *identifiers*.  You can use any spelling conventions you like, because the clients don't care -- in very much the same way that the compiler doesn't care what spellings you use for your variable names.

Of course, if it really doesn't matter (and it really doesn't), then using resource names following the usual "this convention for a collection; that convention for an element of the collection" is also fine.

> Should I use the same URL GET http://xxxx/customers but somehow asking for the HTML view, not the data?

With almost any question about REST, the appropriate heuristic is to ask "how did we do it with web browsers and HTML?"

The basic idea is that a *resource* (aka a "document") could have many different representations.  Clients can use the [Accept](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.3.2) to announce to the server the media-types that it understands for a given context.

Now, the interesting thing is that browsers will send different `Accept` headers for images than they will for javascript or pages.  So how do they know?  Well, they understand HTML, and can therefore distinguish the different flavors of tag (script, a, img, etc), and choose the appropriate header to use when retrieving each.

In other words, you don't just give somebody a link - you also give them hints so that the client can understand the semantics of the link.  [Web Linking](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8288) is a common approach.